# VersionOne Projects & Assets

Tags: versionone

We are looking for guidance to help build a V1 integration.

1. Does VersionOne support custom assets (not custom fields, but asset types)?
2. Are assets configurable by project? In other words, can you configure the assets that appear (are available) in the asset tray for a given project?
3. How can you programmatically retrieve the assets in the asset tray?

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Does VersionOne support custom assets (not custom fields, but asset
>   types)?

No custom asset types.

> Are assets configurable by project? In other words, can you
>   configure the assets that appear (are available) in the asset tray for
>   a given project?

You cannot configure the asset tray for a given project

> How can you programmatically retrieve the assets in the asset tray?

There is no single API call to retrieve the contents of the asset tray so you aren't able to retrieve assets from the asset tray. This is one of the common cases where the VersionOne core app calls a method direct to find data to populate the asset tray. However, you can retrieve the same data indirectly from the VersionOne database by using the VersionOne API or SDK and querying for the last N assets that were updated.